# Is it redundant to use async inside of QThread in PyQt

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, pyqt

I have a class that is basically a QThread that only  has one job that job is to run an async function. Since they both spin off threads is it redundant ? Should I just use one or the other?

```
class BLE_DiscoverServices(QThread):
    BLE_ADDESS= "NONE"
    scan_timeout=5
    discovered_services = pyqtSignal(list)
    def run(self):
        asyncio.run(self.BLE_discoverServices())
```

Comment: As a side note, you don't want to call the function `self.BLE_discoverServices()` - that calls the function and schedules the result.

Comment: Yes, it is redundant, but that only one of the issues with your code